# Configuring MDB to connect to IBM MQ in JBoss EAP6.1

Tags: jboss7.x, ibm-mq

I am trying to configure MDB bundled in WAR to connect to IBM MQ.

I am using @ActivationConfigProperty and trying to define values as a system property. But this is not working.

After looking at the documentation, I found that I have to define like below in standalong-full.xml. But that does not make any sense to me as I am adding application properties into JBoss. If I reinstall JBoss, I have to also remember to add these stuff.

```
<resource-adapter>
<archive>
wm q.jm sra-VERSION.rar
</archive>
<transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
<connection-definitions>
<connection-definition classname="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:jboss/MQ.CONNECTIONFACTORY.NAME"
pool-nam e="MQ.CONNECTIONFACTORY
```

Can anyone please advice any alternate approach.

Thanks in advance and appreciate your help.

Best Regards - Roy

Answer (score 0):

Roy,
You don't need to modify the standalone-full.xml directly. This file gets overwritten by JBoss. The preferred approach is to make these updates via cli, the command line interface. Any changes you make via cli will be written to your standalone-full.xml. Once you are in cli you can issue commands like

```
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=mymq:add(archive="wm q.jm sra-VERSION.rar",transaction-support="NoTransaction")
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=mymq/connection-definitions="TopicConnection":add(class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl",jndi-name="java:jboss/MQ.CONNECTIONFACTORY.NAME",enabled="true",use-java-context="true",use-ccm="true",min-pool-size=1,max-pool-size=20)
```

BTW, why do you have a space in your archive name "wm q.jm ", this may not be an issue, just curious.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to deploy the IBM MQ JCA to JBoss.  This can be done via the web interface or the CLI.  This will result in an entry in your standalone config file similar to:

```
    <deployments>
    <deployment name="wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.5.rar" runtime-name="wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.5.rar">
        <content sha1="b6f5a197dcda61c38215ffc24666d2d028341323"/>
    </deployment>
```

You will then need to create the matching resource adapter configuration section:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.5.rar">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.5.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <config-property name="maxConnections">
                    100
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="reconnectionRetryCount">
                    1000
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="reconnectionRetryInterval">
                    30000
                </config-property>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>
```

Note that the name `wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.5.rar` is used consistently.

In your MDB, you would then have:

```
@MessageDriven(name = "WebSphereMQ", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxPoolDepth", propertyValue="100"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxMessages", propertyValue="1"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "hostName", propertyValue = "10.0.0.150"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "port", propertyValue = "1414"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "channel", propertyValue = "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "queueManager", propertyValue = "QUEUE.MANAGER"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "false"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "${the.queue.name}"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "transportType", propertyValue = "CLIENT") })

@ResourceAdapter(value="wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.5.rar")
public class WebSphereMQ implements MessageListener {
...
...
...
}
```

Note the `@ResourceAdapter` and the `${the.queue.name}`.

The property substitution for annotations must be enabled in the standalone config file:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.2">
        <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>true</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
        <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
        <annotation-property-replacement>true</annotation-property-replacement>
    </subsystem>
```

- Doug